# Reversal Badge not Awarded

Tags: support, badges, reversal-badge

Why I am not awarded Reversal badge for answering  [Query Help: Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526101/query-help-entity-framework/17526463#17526463) Question?

Comment: The badge is for *Score* (upvotes-downvotes) not for *Reputation*.

Comment: Score = upvote - downvote (score is the number you see on the left side of your post)

Comment: Why do you think that you *should* be awarded this badge?

Comment: If only it were that easy to earn that badge.. Hint: Gold badges are generally *harder* to earn than silver badges, which in turn are harder to earn than bronze badges. If you didn't get any bronze or silver badges for an answer, getting *just* a gold badge for the post is highly unlikely.

Comment: Sorry Friends, I made mistake in understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Score means `upvotes - downvotes = 20 upvotes` not 20 reputation